# Why does frequency equal k/K where k=0,..., K-1 in Discrete Fourier Transform?

Tags: signal, dsp, fourier

I totally can't understand why f = k/K. What does k, K means, respectively?. I really want to know what they actually indicate in real world. Or, please give me an example. I spent 2 days night but could't catch the DFT.

Answer (score 2):

The DFT is, essentially, a *sampled* DTFT where the number of samples is \$K\$ and, thus, the spectrum is sampled at frequencies with spacing proportional to \$\frac{1}{K}\$ or, as in the image below, \$\frac{1}{N}\$

[image]

Note the \$k\$ indexes the samples in frequency just as \$n\$ indexes the samples in time.

Comment: You said that "as in the image below, 1/N" And I have read many books, the authors take N samples with DTFT to get DFT.
Why N? I think N is simply the sampling rate in time domain, right. In frequency domain, can we choose other sampling rate to get DFT?